# pig to add column based on value in another column

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a column in tuple called avg_rating. I would like to create a new column NPS based on values in avg_rating. Here is how avg_rating data looks like

```
avg_rating
3
4
8
9
10
```

So if rating >= 8 then Pr
if rating rating is in between  4 & 8 NPS will be P 
if rating is < 4 then NPS will be D

here is what i m trying,

```
yy = FOREACH avg_rating GENERATE avg_rating,((int)wtr>=8 ?'P':(int)wtr>=4 && (int)wtr<8 ?'PR':'D');
```

I am using multiple conditions in turnery operator but gives me error

> > Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near '('

Any idea whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues here.

1. You can't generate avg_rating
2. and instead of &&
3. Another set of parentheses around the embedded ternary.

This parses:

```
avg_rating = load '/tmp' using PigStorage('\t') as (wtr:INT);

yy = FOREACH avg_rating GENERATE 
wtr,
((int)wtr>=8 ? 'P' : ((int)wtr>=4 and (int)wtr<8 ? 'PR' : 'D')) as v;

describe yy;
```